# Opencv Cuda accelerated : Python can't see GPU device

Tags: python, opencv

I installed OpenCV for GPU use in python, following tutorials on youtube.
I encounter a major difficulty when I try to see if python recognizes the GPU.

After the installation, I executed this code, in order to verify if my GPU is detected or not :

```
import cv2
from cv2 import cuda

cuda.printCudaDeviceInfo(0)
```

The first output was :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\include\opencv2/core/private.cuda.hpp:106
: error: (-216:No CUDA support) The library is compiled without CUDA support in function 'throw_no_cuda'
```

So I thought my install was wrong, then I did the install again.
After many attempts, I tried to do the same code verification as before but in the *site-packages* folder of my Miniconda install (In the same location of cv2 for GPU).

And surprisingly, when I use the method `cuda.printCudaDeviceInfo(0)` the output is :

```
*** CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking) ***
Device count: 1

Device 0: "NVIDIA T400"
...
  Compute Mode:
      Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously)

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version  = 11.70, CUDA Runtime Version = 11.70, NumDevs = 1
```

So the GPU has been detected when I used python in this folder.
But my want is to use python in other folders.
I thought it was a **PATH** error, but I added to my path, the cv2 location in my variables system environment, and I got the same result.

Does anyone have an idea about how to fix this ?
Thank you.

Comment: I precise that I added to my path the path defined as following to point on cv2:  C:\Users\sebastien.grand\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages

Comment: When you built opencv, did you point the cmake file to your python directory? So opencv would install there.

Comment: I built the binaries here : C:/Users/sebastien.grand/OpenCV/build, it's not my python directory but the lib cv2 is present in my libs.